Circular linked list, destructor delete order causing seg-fault
Overview
I have a simple circularly linked list I was making for demonstration purposes (I know I should be using smart pointers, but this is a pedagogical exercise for memory and data structures).
Part of the process is to demonstrate recursion as well, and so all of the functions are written recursively.
I was having trouble when it came to freeing the memory from the circularly linked list.
Broken code
void CLL::clear() {
    if (!rear) { return; }

    clear(rear->next);
    rear = nullptr;
}

void CLL::clear(Node*& curr) {
    if (curr != rear) {
        clear(curr->next);
    }

    delete curr;
    curr = nullptr;
}

Code replacement (fixes broken code; unsure of why)
void CLL::clear() {
    if (!rear) { return; }

    clear(rear);
}

void CLL::clear(Node*& curr) {
    if (curr->next != rear) { // continue recursion if we're not at the end
        clear(curr->next);
    }

    delete curr;
    curr = nullptr;
}

GDB context
Breakpoint 1, CLL::clear (this=0x7fffffffdce8, curr=@0x55555556b6e8: 0x55555556b2b0) at CLL.cpp:36
36      if (curr != rear) {
(gdb) n
37          clear(curr->next);
(gdb) 
Breakpoint 1, CLL::clear (this=0x7fffffffdce8, curr=@0x55555556b2b8: 0x55555556b6e0) at CLL.cpp:36
36      if (curr != rear) {
(gdb) 
40      delete curr;
(gdb) 
41      curr = nullptr;
(gdb) 
42  }
(gdb) 
CLL::clear (this=0x7fffffffdce8, curr=@0x55555556b6e8: 0x8954fb37e656c2a4) at CLL.cpp:40
40      delete curr;
(gdb) 
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff78a53fe in __GI___libc_free (mem=0x8954fb37e656c2a4) at ./malloc/malloc.c:3368
3368    ./malloc/malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)

Rest of code (for context)
CLL.cpp
#include "CLL.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout, std::endl;

// [DE]CONSTRUCTORS
CLL::~CLL() {
    clear();
}

// HELPER FUNCTIONS
void CLL::clear() {
    if (!rear) { return; }

    clear(rear->next);
    rear = nullptr;
}

void CLL::clear(Node*& curr) {
    if (curr != rear) {
        clear(curr->next);
    }

    delete curr;
    curr = nullptr;
}

void CLL::insert(int _data, size_t index) {
    if (!rear) {
        rear = new Node(_data);
        rear->next = rear;
    }   
    else { 
        insert(_data, index, rear->next);
    }   
}       
    
void CLL::insert(int _data, size_t index, Node*& curr) {
    // base case 1: insert after rear (this becomes the new rear)
    if ((index == 1) and (curr == rear))
    {
        rear->next = new Node(_data, rear->next);
        rear = rear->next;
    }
    // base case 2: insert before the rear
    else if (index == 0) {
        curr = new Node(_data, curr);
    }

    // recursive case
    else {
        insert(_data, index-1, curr->next);
    }
}

void CLL::display() const {
    display(rear->next);
    cout << "->..." << endl;
}

void CLL::display(const Node* const & curr) const {
    cout << curr->data;
    if (curr != rear) {
        cout << "->";
        display(curr->next);
    }
}

size_t CLL::size() const {
    if (!rear) { return 0u; }

    return size(rear->next);
}

size_t CLL::size(const Node* const & curr) const {
    if (curr == rear) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 1 + size(curr->next);
    }
}

CLL.h
#pragma once

#include <cstddef> //size_t

class CLL {
private:
    struct Node {
        int data;
        Node* next;

        Node(): data(0), next(nullptr) {}
        Node(int _data): data(_data), next(nullptr) {}
        Node(int _data, Node* _next):
            data(_data), next(_next) {}
    };  
        
    // HELPER FUNCTIONS
    void clear();
            
    // RECURSIVE FUNCTIONS
    void clear(Node*&);
    void insert(int, size_t, Node*&);
    void display(const Node* const &) const;
    size_t size(const Node* const &) const;
    
    Node* rear;
public:
    CLL(): rear(nullptr) {}
    CLL(const CLL &) = delete; // don't copy (for now)
    ~CLL();
    
    void insert(int, size_t);
    void display() const;
    size_t size() const;
};

main.cpp
#include "CLL.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // rand(), srand(..)
#include <ctime> // time(..)
    
using std::cout, std::cerr, std::endl;
    
int main() {
    CLL list;

    srand(time(NULL));
    
    // insert randomly in list
    for (int n: {1,2}) { 
        size_t insert_index = rand() % (list.size() + 1);
        // output info
        cerr << "inserting " << n << "@" << insert_index;
        if (insert_index == list.size()) {
            cerr << " (rear)"; 
        }
        cerr << endl;
    
        list.insert(n, insert_index);
        list.display();
    }
 
    cout << '\n';
    list.display(); 
    cout << "The CLL has " << list.size() << " elements" << endl;

    return 0;
}

I tried changing the amount of data, but anything beyond one datum seems to break the code.
I think that the error has to do with order of deletion, seeing as how that's the only real difference from the original to the fixed solution. I'm not sure what causes it though.
Although the rear field gets deleted last in the fixed version, but is deleted first in the broken version, shouldn't the stack frames hold the proper addresses and free the memory correctly, regardless?

Your clear overload that accepts a Node should check for null

@AndyG The first line in the wrapper function should act as a guard-clause for null pointers: if (!rear) { return; }

No, you should not be using smart pointers in linked lists.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Why shouldn't I? I've been taught that it's best practice to handle memory with smart pointers whenever dealing with dynamic memory?

"use it whenever" yes, until it doesn't work. And here it doesn't work. For one, you cannot freely  use smart pointers in a circular list, you need a destructor to break the cycle. For two, a too large linked will cause a stack overflow in recursive calls to node destructors. Plus it doesn't make sense, as all nodes are logically owned by the list, rather than by a preceding node.

Btw none of your functions should be recursive in real life, for the same reason of crashing with large lists.

clear also does not advance  current, is this your intent?

@PepijnKramer yes, the advancement occurs as a result of the recursive call

@Amiel Smart "pointers" are not for managing memory, they are for managing ownership.

The call stack is
  clear();
   clear(rear->next);
     clear(rear->next->next);
      delete rear->next->next; [1]
      rear->next->next = nullptr
     delete rear->next; [2]
     rear->next = nullptr [3]

Note that rear->next->next points back to rear, so after you call delete rear->next->next and goes back to [2],[3], rear will point to already freed memory, when you try to delete rear->next or set rear->next to nullptr (curr = nullptr; in your code), you are actually access already freed memory.

Building your program with g++ -fsanitize=address ... and running it results in the following error:
$ ./a.out
inserting 1@0 (rear)
1->...
inserting 2@1 (rear)
1->2->...

1->2->...
The CLL has 2 elements
=================================================================
==2132753==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x502000000038 at pc 0x5651fedd999c bp 0x7fff3f6e0970 sp 0x7fff3f6e0968
READ of size 8 at 0x502000000038 thread T0
    #0 0x5651fedd999b in CLL::clear(CLL::Node*&) /tmp/CLL.cpp:24
    #1 0x5651fedd98c9 in CLL::clear() /tmp/CLL.cpp:15
    #2 0x5651fedd9851 in CLL::~CLL() /tmp/CLL.cpp:8
    #3 0x5651fedd9680 in main /tmp/main.cpp:32
    #4 0x7fd8e74456c9 in __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
    #5 0x7fd8e7445784 in __libc_start_main_impl ../csu/libc-start.c:360
    #6 0x5651fedd91c0 in _start (/tmp/a.out+0x21c0) (BuildId: a4b06b664799e1318f7f6a2da32ed21e49c613d4)

0x502000000038 is located 8 bytes inside of 16-byte region [0x502000000030,0x502000000040)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7fd8e7af55c8 in operator delete(void*, unsigned long) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:164
    #1 0x5651fedd99b4 in CLL::clear(CLL::Node*&) /tmp/CLL.cpp:24
    #2 0x5651fedd997a in CLL::clear(CLL::Node*&) /tmp/CLL.cpp:21
    #3 0x5651fedd98c9 in CLL::clear() /tmp/CLL.cpp:15
    #4 0x5651fedd9851 in CLL::~CLL() /tmp/CLL.cpp:8
    #5 0x5651fedd9680 in main /tmp/main.cpp:32
    #6 0x7fd8e74456c9 in __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7fd8e7af46c8 in operator new(unsigned long) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:95
    #1 0x5651fedd9b69 in CLL::insert(int, unsigned long, CLL::Node*&) /tmp/CLL.cpp:42
    #2 0x5651fedd9adb in CLL::insert(int, unsigned long) /tmp/CLL.cpp:34
    #3 0x5651fedd95a8 in main /tmp/main.cpp:23
    #4 0x7fd8e74456c9 in __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free /tmp/CLL.cpp:24 in CLL::clear(CLL::Node*&)

The best way to fix this is to rewrite your code to avoid recursion (which is totally inappropriate for the problem at hand).

Thank you. I didn't know about that compiler option, that clears things up. The recursion is entirely for teaching purposes, I understand it is the wrong tool for the job.
